# What am I? (my first riddle): While swinging my fin I fight for a grin

Tags: riddle

This is my first riddle and I think it should be easy for you guys.

> While swinging my fin I fight for a grin
>   I woosh back and forth
>   Killing millions on both
>   Destroying evil day and night
>   Preventing precious from blight

Comment: It must be sort of hard if no one has got it yet. well done

Comment: I have given hours of thought to it I had fun thinking of it but I really thought you guys would easily solve it :D It's something everyone knows nothing like a strange object nobody would know like I see in some riddles

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are

> a toothbrush.

"While swinging my fin I fight for a grin"

> Pretty literal here: the fin is the brush, the grin is the grin.

"I woosh back and forth"

> Just brushing, you know.

"Killing millions on both"

> Killing the horrible bacteria, of course.

"Destroying evil day and night"

> Well, actually three times a day as a minimum, I hope.

"Preventing precious from blight"

> What's more precious than teeth? Well, ok, golden teeth. And they don't even get blight.

Comment: Exactly!:D Good job!

Comment: Ahhh, I read the "evil" in "Destroying evil day and night" as adjective! That's why I was wondering, what kind of "evil day" are there?

Comment: Ahh, the irony of what I was doing while reading this riddle and yet still unable to figure it out.

Comment: Thats exactly when I came up with the subject for the riddle :D

Comment: @SinanSamet etc. - Attention all riddlers! [Vote](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/are-puzzles-and-riddles-welcome/1681#1681)! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> The Moon

While swinging my fin

> The moon swims through across the sky.

I fight for a grin

> The crescent moon looks like a grin (c.f. The Cheshire Cat).

I woosh back and forth

> The moon goes back and forth across the sky.

Killing millions on both

> The Moon can mark the passage of time. Millions die with every cycle of the Moon.

Destroying evil day and night

> The Moon adds to the light of the night - "evil" is taken darkness.

Preventing precious from blight

> No idea yet

Comment: Nice on but not the right one I'm afraid!

Comment: Yes fair enough... I need to make the last sentence work...

Answer (score 1):

You are a:

> Clock (with a Pendulum)

While swinging my fin I fight for a grin

> The pendulum swings where the shape formed by the motion is a smile/grin.

I woosh back and forth

> The pendulum swings in this way.

Killing millions on both

> Every tick of the clock signals the death of millions.

Destroying evil day and night

> The sounds of the clock striking the hour (like a cuckoo clock) is thought to ward off evil.

Preventing precious from blight

> Not sure :p

Comment: Yet another nice try! The simplicity of the object is right though. But the last sentence is very obvious once you know the answer.

Comment: I think it's some sort of tool used for cleaning, like broom. Perhaps a mop?

Comment: @justhalf maybe... how does it fight for a grin? I suppose much as a pendulum does..

Comment: @justhalf you were right. it was a brush :D